# how to get the current value for any column in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure where i need to check the current value every time in the another query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
set @ct=(select count(alloc_hrs) from emp_sample where week(alloc_date)=<current_value>);
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
  (CONCAT ('MAX(CASE WHEN alloc_date=''',
        alloc_date, 
         ''' THEN @ct END) `',
       year(alloc_date),week(alloc_date),
         'week`'
         ))
 )
  INTO @sql
  FROM emp_sample;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT emp_code, ', @sql,' FROM emp_sample group by emp_code');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- Is there any function like this() in mysql
- If not what should I replace to get that

Comment: replace `<current_value>` with `week(now())`? Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Here a simple example. `update table1 t1 set t1.column = 'table2.value'` so you can attach table name and no need to use `this()`

Comment: @NaveedRamzan What on earth are you talking about? Your update statement isn't even a valid statement.

Comment: I just gave a clue.